# If $v^*Av=1$ implies that $v^*Bv=1$, then is $A=B$?

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $A,B \in \mathbf{M}_{n \times n}(\mathbb{C})$ be hermitian.

If whenever $v^*Av=1$ implies that $v^*Bv=1$, then is $A=B$?

My Approach

1) Fundamental theorem of Algebra may be used for proving this. In the expansion of the equation of $v^*Av=1$, however, there are both $z_i$'s and  conjugates of $z_i$. So I can not apply the theorem directly to my problem.

2) By putting $z_i$ to $x_i+iy_i$ for indeterminates and $\alpha_{ij}$ to $a_{ij}+b_{ij}$ for componests of $A$ or $B$, I can obtain real equations, real parts and imaginary parts, for $v^*Av=1$ and $v^*Bv=1$. Since zeros of real part equation of $v^*Av=1$ are also that of $v^*Bv=1$, I expect that two equations are the same and so $A=B$. But this idea have some gaps. Since coefficients of equations are combinations of components of $A$ and $B$, the argument that two same equations come from the same matrix is required more reasoning.

Is there more simple and clear proof?

In fact, I am not certain that my problem is truth.

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT**

Additional condition:

$\exists v$ s.t. $v^*Av=1$

Comment: As written, the condition (preceeded by the obvious $\forall v$) is satisfied by $A=0$ and $B=I$.

Comment: @G.Sassatelli How is it if  I add the condition that  $A$ and $B$ are invertible?

Comment: Your first line sounds like you have fixed some vector $v$. But the the second line only makes sense if it's an implication for any $v$. Would your question be as you intend it to be if you removed reference to $v$ from the first line, and made the second line be "If whenever $v*Av=1$ implies..."?

Comment: @alex.jordan I edited it. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The statement as it stands isn't true. E.g. when $A$ is negative definite, the statement "$v^\ast Av=1$ implies that $v^\ast Bv=1$" is a vacuous truth for any $B$. It is true, however, if you assume that $u^\ast Au=1$ for some vector $u$.

*Sketch of proof.* By assumption, $v^\ast (A-B)v=0$ whenever $v^\ast Av$ is positive. Pick any $w\in\mathbb C^n$ and define a quadratic polynomial $p(t)=(u+tw)^\ast (A-B)(u+tw)$ in $t\in\mathbb R$. Note that $p(t)=0$ when $t$ is small, because $(u+tw)^\ast A(u+tw)$ is positive for small $t$. Hence $p$ is the zero polynomial and you may continue from here.

Comment: Thank you for your details.

Answer (score 1):

HINT: Show first that $v^* A v = v^* B v$ for any $v$. Then, using a polarization identity, that works for hermitian forms, show that 
$v^* A w = v^* B w$ for any $v$, $w$. From here it should be clear.

Comment: Jeong: Looking at the other proof, I noticed that my proof is not correct. It works only to show that if we have equality for every $v$, then $A= B$.